# Are custom actions supported under iOS reCAPTCHA Enterprise?

Tags: ios, recaptcha-enterprise

I am following the [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-ios-apps#objective-c_1) provided by Google for integrating with iOS app.  They only show an example for calling the `excecute()` method with `RecaptchaAction.login` action.  Within Xcode editor, the **RecaptchaAction** object seems to only have properties for **login** and **signup** but no **custom** like in Android.

What am I missing to be able to execute with a custom action string?

I am working in Objective-C and the current version of RecaptchaEnterprise pod of 18.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own questions: yes.

Buried in the [api documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/ios/client/api/Classes/RecaptchaAction#-initwithcustomaction:) describes creating an `RecaptchaAction` object with custom action.

See below example code for passing a custom action named "CoolAction":

```
    NSString* myAction = @"CoolAction";
    RecaptchaAction* action = [[RecaptchaAction alloc] initWithCustomAction:myAction];
              
    [recaptchaClient execute:action
      completion:^void(NSString* _Nullable  token, NSError* _Nullable error) {
      if (!token) {
        NSLog (@"%@", (RecaptchaError *)error.errorMessage);
        return;
      }
      NSLog (@"%@", token);
    }];
```